# How to convert a javascript string to be used as parameter in Razor method?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

It's probably easy (if possible), but I'm having to learn Razor on-demand and my searches provided no acceptable answers so far. This is what I have in a *cshtml* file, for instance:

```
//Minimal example
var imageHtml = "<img src='@Url.Content("~/Content/images/excel_icon.png")' + ">";
```

I reckon *"~/Content/images/excel_icon.png"* is a C# string, but I need something along these lines:

```
var imageLocation = "Content/images/excel_icon.png"; 
//...
//...

var imageHtml = "<img src='@Url.Content(imageLocation)' + ">";
```

I know I won't be able to use *imageLocation* within Razor as it is a javascript variable, but at first glance some kind of conversion seems to be possible. I just can't see to find a way to do it.

Dumb things I have already tried:

```
'@Url.Content("@imageLocation")'
'@Url.Content(@"imageLocation")'
```

Is it possible be done?

**Edit**

Full code (not by me, btw):

```
function ServiceOpeningAttachmentCallback(result) {
    if (result != null && result.Valid) {
        var imageHtml;
        var url = '@Url.Action("GetAnexo", "Servicos", new {Area = "Atendimento"})?idServicoImagem=' + result.IdServicoImagem + "&localAnexo=" + result.LocalAnexo;

        switch (result.ExtensionFile) {
            case ".JPEG":
            case ".PNG":
            case ".JPG":
            case ".BMP":
            case ".GIF":
                imageHtml = "<li id='li_image' id_servico_imagem='" + result.IdServicoImagem + "'>" +
                                "<img src='" + url + "'><a href='#' onclick=showTinyBox('" + url + "')></a>" +
                                "<a href='#' id='botao_excluir' onclick='excluirAnexo(" + result.IdServicoImagem + ");' class='botao'>excluir imagem</a>" +
                            "</li>";
                $(".galeria").append(imageHtml);
                break;
            case ".XLSX":
            case ".XLS":

                imageHtml = "<li id='li_image' id_servico_imagem='" + result.IdServicoImagem + "'>" +
                                "<img src='@Url.Content("~/Content/imagens/icone_excel_64_x_64.png")' style='width: 64px !important;height: 64px !important;'><a href='#' onclick=openUrlNewTab('" + url + "')></a>" +
                                "<a href='#' id='botao_excluir' onclick='excluirAnexo(" + result.IdServicoImagem + ");' class='botao'>excluir imagem</a>" +
                            "</li>";
                $(".galeria").append(imageHtml);
                break;
            case ".PPTX":
            case ".PPT":

                imageHtml = "<li id='li_image' id_servico_imagem='" + result.IdServicoImagem + "'>" +
                                "<img src='@Url.Content("~/Content/imagens/icone_ppt_64_x_64.png")' style='width: 64px !important;height: 64px !important;'><a href='#' onclick=openUrlNewTab('" + url + "')></a>" +
                                "<a href='#' id='botao_excluir' onclick='excluirAnexo(" + result.IdServicoImagem + ");' class='botao'>excluir imagem</a>" +
                            "</li>";
                $(".galeria").append(imageHtml);
                break;
            case ".DOCX":
            case ".DOC":

                imageHtml = "<li id='li_image' id_servico_imagem='" + result.IdServicoImagem + "'>" +
                                "<img src='@Url.Content("~/Content/imagens/icone_word_64_x_64.png")' style='width: 64px !important;height: 64px !important;'><a href='#' onclick=openUrlNewTab('" + url + "')></a>" +
                                "<a href='#' id='botao_excluir' onclick='excluirAnexo(" + result.IdServicoImagem + ");' class='botao'>excluir imagem</a>" +
                            "</li>";
                $(".galeria").append(imageHtml);
                break;
            case ".TXT":
                imageHtml = "<li id='li_image' id_servico_imagem='" + result.IdServicoImagem + "'>" +
                                "<img src='@Url.Content("~/Content/imagens/icone_txt_64_x_64.png")' style='width: 64px !important;height: 64px !important;'><a href='#' onclick=openUrlNewTab('" + url + "')></a>" +
                                "<a href='#' id='botao_excluir' onclick='excluirAnexo(" + result.IdServicoImagem + ");' class='botao'>excluir imagem</a>" +
                            "</li>";
                $(".galeria").append(imageHtml);
                break;
            case ".PDF":
                imageHtml = "<li id='li_image' id_servico_imagem='" + result.IdServicoImagem + "'>" +
                                "<img src='@Url.Content("~/Content/imagens/icone_pdf_64_x_64.png")' style='width: 64px !important;height: 64px !important;'><a href='#' onclick=openUrlNewTab('" + url + "')></a>" +
                                "<a href='#' id='botao_excluir' onclick='excluirAnexo(" + result.IdServicoImagem + ");' class='botao'>excluir imagem</a>" +
                            "</li>";
                $(".galeria").append(imageHtml);
                break;
            default:
                imageHtml = "<li id='li_image' id_servico_imagem='" + result.IdServicoImagem + "'>" +
                                "<img src='@Url.Content("~/Content/imagens/unknown_file.png")' style='width: 64px !important;height: 64px !important;'><a href='#' onclick=openUrlNewTab('" + url + "')></a>" +
                                "<a href='#' id='botao_excluir' onclick='excluirAnexo(" + result.IdServicoImagem + ");' class='botao'>excluir imagem</a>" +
                            "</li>";
                $(".galeria").append(imageHtml);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

It shows a different thumb in a gallery depending on the extension of an attached file. To make matters worse, I had to copy and paste this code for every view that needed attachments because of things like *id_servico_imagem='" + result.IdServicoImagem*. These may vary depending on the view.

Comment: Can you explain more exact what you want to optain?

Comment: Not sure how to be more explict, I want to convert a javascript string into a C# string in a Razor View, so I can use **that** as a parameter in the *Url.Content(string)* method.

Comment: I'm a little bit confused because of your @Url.Content(imageLocation). Why do you have to wrap it in that function? Why dont you use src link as it is?

Comment: @Html.Raw ?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/razor?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: @M.Hazara I'm minimizing and parameterizing some code, right now there's a switch-case in which each case spills out a ton of repeated html (as string). I generalized everything that I could in that html and now the switch-case only has to define the value of *imageLocation*

Comment: @tic seen it. Not my case. But I already found the right solution :)

Comment: Yes i know situations where you need to switch between strings, but still there is no need to wrap your image url inside Url.Content(). Try drag and drop a image from your content folder into the razor page and see how visual studio is creating your <img> tag.

Comment: And for simple if else situation you can use <img src="@( condition ? '~/Content/image1.png' : '~/Content/image2.png')" style="(.........)"></img>

Comment: @M.Hazara I updated both question and answer with a bigger chunk of real code so you can better grasp my scenario. Hopefully it will give someone in need of a fresh idea some insight as well

Answer (score 0):

My ineptitude in Razor Views led to this question. The solution is pretty simple:

```
var imageLocation = '@Url.Content("~/Content/images/excel_icon.png")';
//...
//...

var imageHtml = "<img src='" + imageLocation + '">";
```

Edit:

Parameterized code for a more general usage:

```
function attachmentCallback(result, params) {
    if (result != null && result.Valid) {
        var idValue= result[params.IdFieldName];
        var url = params.Url + idValue;
        var htmlParcial = params.IdHtml + "='" + idValue+ "'>";

        var imageLocation;
        var imageSize = "' style='width: 64px !important;height: 64px !important;";

        switch (result.ExtensionFile) {
            case ".JPEG":
            case ".PNG":
            case ".JPG":
            case ".BMP":
            case ".GIF":
                imageLocation = url;
                break;
            case ".XLSX":
            case ".XLS":
                imageLocation = '@Url.Content("~/Content/imagens/icone_excel_64_x_64.png")' + imageSize;
                break;
            case ".DOCX":
            case ".DOC":
                imageLocation = '@Url.Content("~/Content/imagens/icone_word_64_x_64.png")' + imageSize;
                break;
            case ".PPTX":
            case ".PPT":
                imageLocation = '@Url.Content("~/Content/imagens/icone_ppt_64_x_64.png")' + imageSize;
                break;
            case ".TXT":
                imageLocation = '@Url.Content("~/Content/imagens/icone_txt_64_x_64.png")' + imageSize;
                break;
            case ".PDF":
                imageLocation = '@Url.Content("~/Content/imagens/icone_pdf_64_x_64.png")' + imageSize;
                break;
            default:
                imageLocation = '@Url.Content("~/Content/imagens/unknown_file.png")' + imageSize;
                break;
        }

        var imageHtml = "<li id='li_image' " + htmlParcial +
            "<img src='" + imageLocation + "'><a href='#' onclick=showTinyBox('" + url + "')></a>" +
            "<a href='#' id='botao_excluir' onclick='excluirAnexo(" + idValue + ");' class='botao'>excluir imagem</a>" +
            "</li>";
        $(".galeria").append(imageHtml);
    }
}
```

Now I just need to define the params argument as something like this and pass it to the function:

```
var params =
{
    Url: '@Url.Action("GetAnexo", "Servicos", new {Area = "Atendimento"})?nrSeq=',
    IdFieldName: 'NrSeq',
    IdHtml: 'nr_seq'
}
```